# Checkbox that adds or removes textbox based on state

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a checkbox that will create a new textbox once clicked. Clicked again, it will remove the textbox.

At the moment, it's just making a load of new textboxes as I don't know how to handle if statements inside of javascript. Can someone point me in the right direction please.

http://jsfiddle.net/v7gdX/

```
        <input id="chk" type="checkbox" value="results" />  Results
        <div id="formContainer">

        </div>
```

And the Javascript

```
function CreateTextbox() {
        var textBox = document.createElement("input");
        textBox.setAttribute("type", "textbox");
        textBox.setAttribute("id", textboxId);
        textboxId++;
        return textBox;
        }

    var textboxId = 0;

    if(textboxId == 0)
    {
    document.getElementById("chk").onclick = function () 
    {
        document.getElementById("formContainer").appendChild(CreateTextbox(textboxId));
        var textboxId = 1;
    }
    }

    else if (textboxId == 1)
    {
        //The code to remove the previosuly made textbox
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `document.getElementById("formContainer").innerHTML = '';` to remove it.

And I change your js code like below:

```
var textboxId=0;
function CreateTextbox() {
    var textBox = document.createElement("input");
    textBox.setAttribute("type", "textbox");
    textBox.setAttribute("id", textboxId);
    textboxId++;
    return textBox;
}

document.getElementById("chk").onclick = function () {
    if (textboxId == 0) {
        document.getElementById("formContainer").appendChild(CreateTextbox(textboxId));
        textboxId = 1;
    } else if (textboxId == 1) {
        document.getElementById("formContainer").innerHTML = '';
        textboxId = 0;
        //The code to remove the previosuly made textbox
    }
}
```

Here is jsfiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/v7gdX/2/

Comment: Thanks heaps, that works exactly as needed. Learned something new too!

Answer (score 1):

Although pktangyue's solution works when there's only one element in the formContainer, it will always erase the entire div.

Also, you're dealing with a checkbox here. It can already tell you whether it is checked or not, you do not have to keep its state yourself.

```
function createTextBox() {
  var textBox = document.createElement("input");
  textBox.setAttribute("type", "text");
  return textBox;
}

var txt;
document.getElementById("chk").onchange = function() {
  var form = document.getElementById("formContainer");
  if(this.checked) {
    txt = createTextBox();
    form.appendChild(txt);
  }
  else
    form.removeChild(txt);
}
```

However, if it's just to hide or show a textbox when you selected a checkbox, generating DOM elements from javascript is kind of bad form. You'd be better off then with writing the text box in html, setting its CSS to

```
display: none;
```

And using javascript like this to toggle it

```
document.getElementById("chk").onchange = function() {
  document.getElementById("myTextBox").style.display = this.checked ? "" : "none";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used check box checked value is true `add text` field if false `remove text box`

```
 var textboxId = 1;
        function CreateTextbox() {
        var textBox = document.createElement("input");
        textBox.setAttribute("type", "textbox");
        textBox.setAttribute("id", textboxId);

        return textBox;
        }


        document.getElementById("chk").onclick = function () 
        { 

        if(document.getElementById("chk").checked) {
            document.getElementById("formContainer").appendChild(CreateTextbox());
        } else {
            document.getElementById("formContainer").innerHTML = '';
            }

        }
```

check this http://jsfiddle.net/pradkumar_n/hjaR5/